# ansible load zshenv and use ENV in another task

Tags: ansible, environment-variables

I'd like to load a zshenv file (using `source` command) and then use the ENVs in another task.

This is what I have. I'm hoping there's a better solution

## files

### directory structure

```
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts.yaml
├── profiles
│   └── macos.yaml
├── roles
│   └── base
│       ├── tasks
│       │   ├── git.yaml
│       │   └── main.yaml
│       └── vars
└── tools
    └── zsh
        └── .zshenv
```

### ./ansible.cfg

```ini
[defaults]
inventory = ./hosts.yaml
roles_path = ./roles/
stdout_callback = yaml
```

### ./hosts.yaml

```yaml
---
all:
  hosts:
    localhost
```

### ./profiles/macos.yaml

```yaml
---

# run MacOS configs

# - hosts: localhost
#   connection: local
#   tags: macos
#   roles:
#     - macos
#     # when: ansible_distribution == "MacOSX"

- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tags: base
  roles:
    - base
```

### ./roles/base/main.yaml

```yaml
---

- import_tasks: tasks/git.yaml
```

#### ./roles/base/git.yaml

```yaml
---

- name: source zshenv
  shell:
    cmd: source ../tools/zsh/.zshenv; echo $GIT_CONFIG_PATH
  register: gitConfigPath

- name: Link gitconfig file
  file:
    # PWD: ./profiles
    src: "{{ ansible_env.PWD }}/../tools/git/.gitconfig"
    dest: "{{ gitConfigPath.stdout }}"
    state: link

# - name: print ansible_env
#   debug:
#     msg: "{{ ansible_env }}"
#
# - name: print gitConfigPath
#   debug:
#     msg: "{{ gitConfigPath.stdout }}"
#
```

### ./tools/zsh/.zshenv

```bash
export XDG_CONFIG_HOME="$HOME/.config"
export GIT_CONFIG_PATH="$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config"
```

## command to run

`ansible-playbook profiles/macos.yaml -v`

PS: It'd be easier to do something like this in ansible

`source tools/zsh/.zshenv && ansible-playbook profiles/macos.yaml -v`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help from [Vladimir Botka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6482561/vladimir-botka), using the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/74924664/3053548

I modified a little bit of his code

## TLDR

- source the zshenv file
- print out all the ENV in the shell session
- store the output to as ansible facts
- access the ENV in a task

## Files

### ./profiles/macos.yaml

```yaml
---

# run MacOS configs

- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tags: always
  tasks:
    - name: source zshenv
      shell:
        cmd: source ../tools/zsh/.zshenv; env
      register: out
      changed_when: false
      tags: always

    - name: store zshenv as fact
      set_fact:
        zshenv: "{{ dict( out.stdout.splitlines() | map('split', '=', 1) ) }}"
      changed_when: false
      tags: always

# - hosts: localhost
#   connection: local
#   tags: macos
#   roles:
#     - macos
#     # when: ansible_distribution == "MacOSX"

- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tags: base
  roles:
    - base
```

### ./roles/base/tasks/git.yaml

```yaml
---

- name: Link gitconfig file
  file:
    src: "{{ ansible_env.PWD }}/../tools/git/.gitconfig"
    dest: "{{ zshenv.GIT_CONFIG_PATH }}"
    state: link
```

## command to run

`ansible-playbook profiles/macos.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

Given the simplified project without a role

```bash
shell> tree -a .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
├── pb.yml
└── tools
    ├── git
    └── zsh
        └── .zshenv
```

```bash
shell> cat hosts
localhost
```

```bash
shell> cat tools/zsh/.zshenv 
export GIT_CONFIG_PATH=/home/admin/git/.gitconfig
export ENV1=env1
export ENV2=env2
export ENV3=env3
eval "$(direnv hook zsh)"
```

Parse the environment on your own. For example

```yaml
  zshenv: "{{ dict(lookup('file', 'tools/zsh/.zshenv').splitlines()|
                   select('match', '^\\s*export .*$')|
                   map('regex_replace', '^\\s*export\\s+', '')|
                   map('split', '=')) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  zshenv:
    ENV1: env1
    ENV2: env2
    ENV3: env3
    GIT_CONFIG_PATH: /home/admin/git/.gitconfig
```

Then, use the dictionary *zshenv*

```yaml
    - name: Link gitconfig file
      file:
        dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/tools/git/.gitconfig"
        src: "{{ zshenv.GIT_CONFIG_PATH }}"
        state: link
```

gives, running with *--check -- diff* options

```yaml
TASK [Link gitconfig file] *******************************************************************
--- before
+++ after
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
 path: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-116/tools/git/.gitconfig
-state: absent
+state: link

changed: [localhost]
```

---

Notes

1. Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    zshenv: "{{ dict(lookup('file', 'tools/zsh/.zshenv').splitlines()|
                     select('match', '^\\s*export .*$')|
                     map('regex_replace', '^\\s*export\\s+', '')|
                     map('split', '=')) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: zshenv

    - name: Link gitconfig file
      file:
        dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/tools/git/.gitconfig"
        src: "{{ zshenv.GIT_CONFIG_PATH }}"
        state: link
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  zshenv:
    ENV1: env1
    ENV2: env2
    ENV3: env3
    GIT_CONFIG_PATH: /home/admin/git/.gitconfig

TASK [Link gitconfig file] *******************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

The link *`tools/git/.gitconfig -> /home/admin/git/.gitconfig`* was created

```bash
shell> tree -a .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
├── pb.yml
└── tools
    ├── git
    │   └── .gitconfig -> /home/admin/git/.gitconfig
    └── zsh
        └── .zshenv
```

2. You can use the dictionary *zshenv* to set the *environment*. For example,

```yaml
    - command: echo $GIT_CONFIG_PATH
      environment: "{{ zshenv }}"
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: out.stdout
```

gives

```yaml
  out.stdout: /home/admin/git/.gitconfig
```

3. Cache the dictionary if you want to use this environment globally in the whole play. For example,

```ini
shell> grep fact_caching ansible.cfg
fact_caching = jsonfile
fact_caching_connection = /tmp/ansible_cache
fact_caching_prefix = ansible_facts_
fact_caching_timeout = 86400
```

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        zshenv: "{{ dict(lookup('file', 'tools/zsh/.zshenv').splitlines()|
                         select('match', '^\\s*export .*$')|
                         map('regex_replace', '^\\s*export\\s+', '')|
                         map('split', '=')) }}"
        cacheable: true
```

Then,

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  environment: "{{ zshenv }}"
  tasks:
    - command: echo $GIT_CONFIG_PATH
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: out.stdout
```

gives

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [command] *******************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  out.stdout: /home/admin/git/.gitconfig

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=7    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Is there a away to get the resolved path from ENV.

Ex: zshenv

```bash
export XDG_CONFIG_HOME="$HOME/.config"
export GIT_CONFIG_PATH="$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config"
```

Using your code returns `"$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config"`

Was expecting to get `/home/user/.config/git/config`

Comment: Yes. It is. But, you should first answer the question: "How will the PATH be resolved?" The only answer, IMHO, is by running the shell. The example in 2nd note does it.